# How can I make ls and xargs combined omit path

Tags: bash, ls

I have a folder called lib. In that folder are some files. I want to obtain all the names of the files that end in .jar, and concatenate them into a line, separated by spaces. I don't want the path name at all.

I've tried this:

```
ls lib/*.jar | xargs
```

and the output is

```
lib/file1.jar lib/file2.jar
```

But what I'm trying to get is

```
file1.jar file2.jar
```

How can I do this?

I've also tried find but I get the same problem

```
find lib -name *.jar | xargs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And another `find lib -maxdepth 1 -name *.jar -printf '%f\n' | xargs`

```
          %f     File's  name  with any leading directories removed (only
                 the last element).
```

Comment: I like your answer more than mine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, though it seems there should be an easier (i.e. less hackish and prettier) way:

```
$ ls lib/*.jar | xargs -n 1 basename | xargs
```

Comment: For my purposes, this was simple enough and worked fine- I just dropped the last pipe to xargs to get my list with a newline after each result.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that you can achieve the same in different ways:
If you use bash, you can do:

`for i in lib/*.jar; do echo ${i#*/}; done|xargs`

or

`echo $(for i in lib/*.jar; do echo ${i#*/}; done)`

Answer (score 0):

basename from coreutils is an option.
`find lib -maxdepth 1 -name *.jar -exec basename {} \; | xargs`

---

Blatantly ripped from [Mark Wagner](https://serverfault.com/users/48857), but without the extra call to xargs.
`find lib -maxdepth 1 -name *.jar -printf '%f '`

Comment: Your second command lacks spaces between the filenames and a terminating newline.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Fair point about the lack of space, fixed. Not sure that the newline matters, but it's easy enough to `&& echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if you're going to use find it would be better to just use -exec rather than piping to xargs. That way the original problem's solved because there's no need to remove the path from the filename.

Comment: Can you add the full command example please?